# trying to change the type of a column based on the column name

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I have a dataframe with columns such as 'ID', 'AGE', 'END_DATE', 'START_DATE' etc.
I want to change the type of any column in my dataframe that has the word 'DATE' in it from a float to an integer (so columns like 'END_DATE', 'START_DATE' and others) .

Currently the values in my columns that have 'DATE' in their names are floats like 20230329.0 and I would like to change them to integers to remove the decimal so I would get 20230329. Is there a way I can do this?

My attempt at this was

```
if df.columns.str.contains('DATE'):
   df[df.columns] = df.columns.astype(int)
```

But I am not sure how to apply this condition to only the columns that are named with 'DATE'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.loc` accessor:

```
date_cols = df.columns.str.contains('DATE')
df.loc[:, date_cols] = df.loc[:, date_cols].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will convert only the columns that have 'DATE' in their name from float to integer type.

```
date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'DATE' in col]
df[date_cols] = df[date_cols].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use a loop, you can try this:

```
for x in df.columns:
    if 'DATE' in x and df[x].dtype == 'float':
        df[x] = df[x].astype(int)
```

It takes into account both 'DATE' string and column type

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```
df.astype({i:'int' for i in df.columns if 'DATE' in i})
```